# Is there any point of an Activity with one fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

All the reasons I can find for using Fragments in Android activities have to do with having the ability to display multiple classes/view in the same screen, encapsulating multiple logical components, etc.

Considering all this, it seems, fragments are only actually useful when you employ the use of many of them.

Is that so? Is there ever a point of using just one fragment in an activity?

I ask now because I saw an option on Android Studio to do just that, and I am wondering what the point is.

[image: Android Studio New Activity with Fragment]

Comment: No match sense, you are right. But, you can reuse that Fragment in other activities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of my personal opinion, I would say **yes**.

For the following reasons:

- Assuming you are familiar with Fragments, creating a Fragment is hardly any extra work plus has the following benefits
- Fragments can easily be reused somewhere else (possibly another Activity that has more Fragments, furthermore, Fragments do not necessarily need to use up the full screen).
- Activity transitions are more expensive, Fragment transitions are more sophisticated.
- The Fragment animation framework is better (in terms of usability and performance).
- I always like to keep the number of Activities to a minimum which keeps the AndroidManifest.xml short and clean.
- UI separated into Fragments leads to cleaner code structure and easier code maintenance.

According to google coding guidelines, it is best practice to create as few Activities as possible, and create multiple Fragments instead that are switched inside an Activity.

Comment: your last two points seem quite weak - first one is purely personal preference. About second one - could you explain how adding an extra layer makes code cleaner, better structured or easier to maintain. About your last remark - yes it is advisable not to create extra activities, but we are discussing an activity with only one fragment so this argument does not apply.

Comment: @Okas well, having more activities clutters the AndroidManifest, you don't need to declare Fragments.

Comment: @Zhuiden, you really got to have a lot of activities before they start to clutter AndroidManifest. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends, if you are going to use that fragment in another activity yea, you have a "point" and maybe in a future you can reuse it on another activity, but in the case for example of a splash screen well, it don't have a point. All depend in the uses you want to give to your application.

Answer (score 0):

**Pros:**

-> reusable piece of code

- easy to utilize it again in any module
- easy to debug

-> handles orientation changes better than activity using setRetainInstance(true)

-> great help when scale the app in future for multipane layouts or multi-screen support

**Cons:**

-> little overhead and time consuming if you are not familiar with fragments

Comment: Luckily, fragments aren't **that** complicated, basically it's just that what you had in `onCreate()` will be in `onCreateView()` with two extra lines.

Comment: @Zhuinden: yes, it is simple.only we need to handle fragment manager and backstack properly.